# Website performance - recommended image, js and css sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I'm looking at performance issue on one of site built by external vendors. I see a large number of images, css and js being loaded.

What are the industry recommended image, css and js sizes per page (to optimize performance).

Also I read that all the JS scripts should be on footer just belore close body tag. But if we  do this we get Jquery exceptions.

Finally what should be the normal page load time?

Thanks.

Comment: Your load time should be less than 4 seconds. That is pretty universally known.

Comment: You can also use a program called JpegMini to compress your images. Consider removing some of the largest files.

Comment: Code files (javascript, jquery, html, css) almost take no time to load. Your problem is with large media files.

Comment: Consider using html entities for icons. There is a large collection of entities available which would reduce the number of icons on your site! Check out http://www.amp-what.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many techniques for reducing page load times.

Here are some tips for you.

- The page should load in less than 4 seconds
- Remove unnecessary media files (try using html entities instead http://www.amp-what.com/)
- Compress your media with available programs on the internet (I use a program called JpegMini for images and Switch for audio).
- You don't really need to worry about code files like `.css, .html, .js, and others` because they are usually only a few kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "industry standard". Your page should be as ligh as possible.

Neither does exist normal page load time because of differences in connection speed.

There is the same rule for both speed and size, it should be as fast/light as possible with keeping content and UI nice for users.

Answer (score 0):

When I built my website, this is also one of the problems I ran into. There are multiple ways to make your website load faster. If your pages  contain a lot of photos than you may notice that during a browser session, the first time you open up a page the pictures may slowly load and it doesn't look professional when that happens. One one around this is to create a javascript function that loads all images into the cache once when the index page is loaded. This make loading the home page slightly slower, but navigating through the rest of the site should be quick and smooth.

Another method is to load images into what is known as a sprite sheet. These are often used into game programming and it basically the same idea as my previous method,but with a sprite sheet, all of your images on located on the same file and you access certain ones by changing the dimension that are displayed in your web browser. Basically, it loads all your images in a single time.

Another approach is to make the dimensions of your image small then re-size them using CSS. I am not a big fan of doing it this way because although the images load faster due to less data being transferred, sometimes re-sizing the images can be tricky and if I recall correctly, can make them a bit fuzzy if you adjust them too much. Hope this helps.